# Given a Turing Machine M and a string $x$ how do we tell whether a the Turing Machine M loops on the string $x$

Tags: computability, turing-machines, halting-problem

Let us say there is a Turing Machine $M$ and a string $x$.  So now I want to know if $M$ accepts or rejects the string or loops on it. So, I feed the string to $M$. So, if $M$ is accept or reject the string it would halt after a finite time and I would get my answer.  But how do I know if the machine loops on the string or not.

One possible way is to see if a configuration repeats itself. However, the machine has no way of knowing  if the configuration has occurred before because it cannot store them . So, we would never get an answer. So, how will I be able to tell whether or not $x$ is accpted or rejected or looped upon by $M$.

Comment: This problem refers to the Halting problem .  you can never make sure if the machine loops forever on a specific input String. You can only recognize this language , you cannot decide this language.

Comment: Why do you think that your loop-testing TM couldn't store the configurations of the machine being tested? Conceptually, at least, you could store them on another tape.

Answer (score 3):

Halting problem is generally unsolvable. The states don't have to repeat. But if you know that they will, see [cycle detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection).